# Python - Retrieve specific "object" from url with Beatifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Im trying to parse a specific "item" on a site, but I dont know if its a class, object, id or something else

my code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(myURL))
divdata = soup.find('div')
print(divdata)
```

And it returns:

```
<div data-store='{"Auth":{"cookie":null,"user":null,"timestamp":1485297666762},"Blocked":{},"Broadcast":
{"forceUpdate":false,"failed":[],"pending":[],"error":
{"isNotFound":false,"isServerError":false,"isUnavailable":false}},"BroadcastCache":{"broadcasts":{"ID1":{"broadcast":
{"data":{"class_name":"Broadcast","id":"ID1","state":"running,
....(more)....
```

So I want to retrieve the "running" or what ever is in "state"
I tried

```
statedata = soup.find('div', {"class":"state"})
```

But it returns nothing, what is the correct way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
div_tag = soup.find('div', {'data-store':True})
data_string = div_tag['data-store']  # get data string
json.loads(data_string)['BroadcastCache']['broadcasts']['ID1']['broadcast']['data']['state'] # convert data string to python dict and get state
```

out:

```
'running'
```

Comment: Is the output stoed in "json" or how does that work? And would all the other "classes" have to come prior in the same order then?

Comment: @Yoshidk this string is json formated, use `json.loads()` to convert it to python dict and you can access the data through this dict object.

Answer (score -1):

The correct syntax is `soup.find_all('div', class_='state')`.

Note the underscore after `class_`.

It's unlikely to work in your case without modification, since it looks like the actual class of the div is 'data-store', and the rest is just a string and not actually content of a tag. You could just use `string.find('\"state\"')` on that one.

Comment: Yea I cant get it to work either. I dont think it returns a string